# Using Classic editor with visual studio 2019 and Windows 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, sdk, azure-pipelines

##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\McoAgent_work_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0. Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0. [C:\McoAgent_work\337\s\MBLCCAPI\M
logs_26543.zip
CC.API.csproj]

pool:
name: Mco
demands:

msbuild
visualstudio
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Build_Server_Name’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:

task: UseDotNet@2
displayName: ‘Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.401’
inputs:
version: 6.0.401

task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
displayName: 'Use NuGet ’

task: NuGetCommand@2
displayName: ‘NuGet restore’
inputs:
restoreSolution: ‘$/MBC/MBC-Core/MBCAPI.sln’

task: VSBuild@1
displayName: ‘Build solution’
inputs:
solution: ‘$/MBC/MBC-Core/MBCAPI.sln’
vsVersion: 16.0

task: CopyFiles@2
displayName: 'Copy Files ’
inputs:
SourceFolder: ‘$/MBC/MBC-Core’
Contents: ‘**/*’
TargetFolder: ‘$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)’

task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
displayName: ‘Publish Artifact’
inputs:
publishLocation: FilePath
TargetPath: ‘$(Build_Server_Name)\BuildArtifact$(Build.DefinitionName)$(Build.BuildNumber)’

Comment: Regarding the `nuget command failed` error, has it affected the `NuGet restore` step? Have you tried with the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` with restore command to reproduce the issue? Can you please share the [pipeline definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-classic-pipelines?view=azure-devops#export-your-classic-pipeline) and [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) of the affected pipeline in the post?

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the answer below? If the answer can resolve your concerns, please consider accepting it, which may help others encountering similar issues. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET 6 SDK is not available for VS 2019. To use .NET 6 SDK in VS, you need to install VS 2022 at least.

[image]

More details, see:

- [Install with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60#install-with-visual-studio)
- [.NET SDK, MSBuild, and Visual Studio versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/versioning-sdk-msbuild-vs)

Comment: @DarshanC, Is the answer helpful for you? And is there any update from you?